# Centering One or Two DIVs Dynamically

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

I am trying to get a page with 3 DIVS Left|Center|Right, that can display Center, Left|Center, Center|Right in the center of a wrapper div.

I'm using jQuery toggle to toggle either the Left, Right, or both DIVS off (display:none). I have tried several methods without success. If I make the DIVS inline-block and use align-text: center, then text in the DIVS gets the unwanted formatting. If I float all DIVS left and then make the wrapping div width: 80%;    margin: 0 auto;, this only semi centers them and adds useless margins which when re-sizing the browser will make one of the DIVS go to the next line more quickly then if the width was 100%.

Ex. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cjf4Q/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">ONE</div>
    <div id="center">TWO</div>
    <div id="right">THREE</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
#left{
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #880000;
    float: left;
}
#center{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000088;
    float: left;
}
#right{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #008800;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: can´t see any jquery in your fiddle, use position:relative  float left and right

Comment: In jsfiddle I just manually set the display: none

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

### Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="centering">
        <div id="left">ONE</div>
        <div id="center">TWO</div>
        <div id="right">THREE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
}
.centering{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
#left{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #880000;
    float: left;
}
#center{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000088;
    float: left;
}
#right{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #008800;
    float: left;
}
```

You could add in a media query to handle what happens when `#wrapper` gets too small for its containing divs. That or just give wrapper a `min-width` as I have.

Comment: When I set the display: none to either the left, right or both of those, the remaining divs which are showing become uncentered.

Answer (score 0):

The method I ended up using was a wrapper div with margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto;, then having all the divs inside the wrapper float left. The wrapper div then had its width set via JavaScript to the total of the visible divs inside it whenever a toggle change occurred.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to set correct `display: table/-cell` values. And remove `width` to `#wrapper`

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">ONE</div>
    <div id="center">TWO</div>
    <div id="right">THREE</div>
</div>

<style>
    #wrapper {display: table; margin: auto; width: auto;}
    #wrapper div {display: table-cell;}
    /* #wrapper #left {display: none} */ /* uncomment to hide just two cells */ 
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cjf4Q/35/ // 3 cells
http://jsfiddle.net/cjf4Q/34/ // 2 cells

This solution works without setting of fixed width to `#wrapper`, you can dynamically change sizes and it will still fit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for if i'm not mistaken:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    min-width:300px;
}

#wrapper div{
    top:0;
}

#left{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #880000;
    left: 0px;
   position:absolute;
}
#center{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000088;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
#right{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #008800;
    right: 0px;
    position:absolute;
}
```